# Display Table Cell Content onClick If corresponding Checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Table as follows.. I need to Display Table Cell Content If corresponding Checkbox is checked on button Click

[image]

For eg:

> If **Row2** is checked, alert box should say **Row2**

Here is my code,

> **JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function whichRow(tableID){ 
 var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 for(var i=0; i<rowCount-1; i++) {
 var cell_val=table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
 alert(cell_val);
}
}
</script>
```

> **HTML:**

```
<table id="Item1">
 <tr><td>Row 1</td><td><input name="rowno" type="checkbox"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 2</td><td><input name="rowno" type="checkbox"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 3</td><td><input name="rowno" type="checkbox"  /></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" onclick="whichRow('Item1')" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

> **Problem that I am facing:**

Currently I am able to retrieve innerHTML of checkbox but unable to find out whether its checked or not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can try it this way.

**EDIT** Updated based on comments

```
function whichRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var inputBoxes = table.getElementsByTagName('input'); //modified to get only input tags present within the table
    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount - 1; i++) {
        if (inputBoxes[i].checked) { //checks if the checkbox is selected
            var cell_val = table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML;
            alert(cell_val);
        }
    }
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/NzRae/)

Comment: Harry hope my edit is good enough it is just a suggestion as I understood his mean.

Comment: @Harry : what do you mean by OP ?

Comment: well my edit just inserted a bit to yours and did not change yours but that's ok as you wish.

Comment: @Harry : What if similar checkboxes are present outside the table.
document.getElementsByName('rowno') this will read from entire document. I want to read it from table alone ?

Comment: @Harry : I need it in Javascript. He is giving suggesting jQuery. Thats why i accepted your answer. Pls help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36196/discussion-between-logan-and-harry)

Answer (score 1):

Without jQuery

```
function whichRow(tableID){ 
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID), inpt, chks;

    //if querySelectorAll is present use it else fallback gracefully
    if(table.querySelectorAll){
        chks = table.querySelectorAll('input[name=rowno]');
    } else {
        var temp = table.getElementsByTagName('input');
        chks = [];
        for(var i=0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            inpt = temp[i];
            if(inpt.name == 'rowno'){
                chks.push(inpt);
            }
        }
    }

    for(var i=0; i < chks.length; i++) {
        inpt = chks[i];
        if(inpt.name == 'rowno' && inpt.checked){
            alert(chks[i].parentNode.previousSibling.innerHTML)
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8xRxc/)

With jQuery - Cross Browser

```
function whichRow(tableID){ 
    $('#' + tableID).find('input[name="rowno"]:checked').each(function(){
        alert($(this).closest('td').prev().text())
    })
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YBjVC/)

Comment: what about for previous versions of browsers ?

Comment: @logan choose the answer provided by Harry ... but if you have jQuery look at the jQuery solution provided above it works for all browsers

Comment: document.getElementsByName('rowno') will read from entire document. I want to read it from table alone to avoid any duplications in any the page

Comment: @logan yes it is, it uses a graceful fallback by using `querySelectorAll` if available else falls back to use [element.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName)

Comment: @logan also why don't you use jQuery here since you have tagged the question with it, with that you don't have to worry about cross browser support

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36195/discussion-between-logan-and-arun-p-johny)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the jQuery version. In this case, there's  no need to pass the parent table `id` through the `onclick` event handler.

```javascript
$('#button').on('click', function() {  
  var selected = $(this).parents('table')
                 .find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
                      return $.trim($(this).parent().prev('td').text());
                 }).get().join();
  // Remove the .join() method to get the array instead
  console.log(selected);
});
```

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/oXoQafo/2/edit)**

Comment: @logan Check the console :) It doesn't alert anything. or simply change the `console.log()` to `alert()`.